# openssl: Not able to verify 3rd in the chain with self-signed certificate

Tags: certificates, openssl

(Disclaimer: Checked all the openssl related topics, no success).

OpenSSL version: `OpenSSL 1.1.1s  1 Nov 2022`

I'm trying to generate the chain of certificates, `root -> intermediate -> user1,user2,user4` but OpenSSL complains in the verification step of the user certificate with root certificate.

My batch script, which generated `3` certificates, and signs then with previous one is:

```
@echo OFF

:: Generate root certificate and self sign it
echo "generate root CA"
openssl genrsa -out rootCA.key 4096
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 1024 -out rootCA.crt -subj "/C=US/ST=CA/O=MyOrg, Inc./CN=root"

:: Intermediate certificate, signed with root CA
echo "generate intermediate CA"
openssl genrsa -out intermediate.key 2048
openssl req -new -sha256 -key intermediate.key -subj "/C=US/ST=CA/O=MyOrg, Inc./CN=intermediate" -out intermediate.csr
openssl x509 -req -in intermediate.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out intermediate.crt -days 500 -sha256 -extensions v3_ca -extfile x509-extensions.cnf

:: User 1 certificate, signed by intermediate certificate
echo "generate user1 CA"
openssl genrsa -out user1.key 2048
openssl req -new -sha256 -key user1.key -subj "/C=US/ST=CA/O=MyOrg, Inc./CN=user1" -out user1.csr -out user1.csr
openssl x509 -req -in user1.csr -CA intermediate.crt -CAkey intermediate.key -CAcreateserial -out user1.crt -days 500 -sha256 -extensions v3_ca -extfile x509-extensions.cnf

:: Print
echo "print certificates"
openssl x509 -in rootCA.crt -text
openssl x509 -in intermediate.crt -text
openssl x509 -in user1.crt -text

:: Verify user 1 certificate trust chain w/o untrusted mode
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile rootca.crt intermediate.crt
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile rootca.crt user1.crt
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile rootca.crt intermediate.crt user1.crt
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile intermediate.crt user1.crt
```

My extensions file:

```
# ssl-extensions-x509.cnf

[v3_ca]
basicConstraints = CA:TRUE #Tried FALSE too
keyUsage = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
subjectAltName = IP:127.0.0.1, IP:192.168.73.120, IP:192.168.73.121
```

Why I cannot verify `rootCA -> intermediate -> user?`.

```
# This is OK
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile rootca.crt intermediate.crt
# This is NOK - verification fails, which is expected
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile rootca.crt user1.crt
# This is OK only between root and intermediate, not down to user
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile rootca.crt intermediate.crt user1.crt
# This is NOK - verification fails
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile intermediate.crt user1.crt
```

Output (example of generated data):

```
"generate root CA"
Generating RSA private key, 4096 bit long modulus (2 primes)
.................................................................++++
.................................................................................................................................................................................++++
e is 65537 (0x010001)
"generate intermediate CA"
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus (2 primes)
..+++++
.....+++++
e is 65537 (0x010001)
Signature ok
subject=C = US, ST = CA, O = "MyOrg, Inc.", CN = intermediate
Getting CA Private Key
"generate user1 CA"
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus (2 primes)
..................................................................................+++++
................................+++++
e is 65537 (0x010001)
Signature ok
subject=C = US, ST = CA, O = "MyOrg, Inc.", CN = user1
Getting CA Private Key
"print certificates"
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            03:90:a9:60:17:a7:c5:6e:44:d2:a7:ba:c2:ab:17:87:fe:eb:11:5b
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, ST = CA, O = "MyOrg, Inc.", CN = root
        Validity
            Not Before: Nov 16 17:01:56 2023 GMT
            Not After : Sep  5 17:01:56 2026 GMT
        Subject: C = US, ST = CA, O = "MyOrg, Inc.", CN = root
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (4096 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:cd:5e:40:08:6c:e2:e7:17:a6:30:e1:d6:5c:e2:
                    bf:76:51:04:aa:6a:c0:b8:4b:b4:76:4b:22:d2:4b:
                    7d:b4:49:89:a3:80:2f:12:fe:f6:6d:6a:39:7f:49:
                    b8:4e:df:18:a5:1d:1e:9f:7b:3a:64:1d:0e:32:0e:
                    9b:c2:ce:5f:fe:a7:41:a0:b5:f1:d0:98:1f:ae:88:
                    fe:4f:1a:f9:cd:af:50:8f:c4:3f:2e:5b:07:53:4a:
                    8e:cf:2c:8a:77:76:76:f4:c9:83:ef:80:0f:68:9f:
                    29:8c:e7:57:e3:75:31:67:32:e0:91:fd:11:43:7e:
                    5e:5c:c1:d5:27:9c:6b:20:26:12:97:6f:77:4a:13:
                    28:4b:0c:60:01:9a:d6:b4:d9:59:15:74:1a:3c:3f:
                    8d:d0:f7:1a:56:64:ae:04:40:f6:98:e6:28:ae:d2:
                    7c:96:18:29:9b:d6:d8:35:4f:a6:4e:54:8c:ed:9e:
                    c4:7e:94:3e:24:2f:a9:f3:93:d2:5a:8f:80:58:41:
                    f6:8d:6e:6e:0a:59:dc:90:fd:c2:e6:82:a6:5d:35:
                    78:30:2e:4a:ea:00:4f:26:20:7b:67:67:0a:b5:17:
                    44:97:97:7b:13:2f:64:b0:d2:d5:33:e2:0a:42:71:
                    28:a1:17:b0:04:ff:60:93:3a:da:53:33:ab:82:fd:
                    70:43:a7:6f:e3:0d:a2:a4:12:32:ce:8e:46:6a:13:
                    e3:68:15:d3:8a:6c:0c:ca:4c:d5:31:84:76:8d:ad:
                    57:e9:c6:28:d5:23:38:b5:ad:91:37:fe:4f:15:c5:
                    bb:9f:b8:df:f4:78:37:86:5d:6a:2a:09:0d:93:24:
                    fa:e2:16:80:14:8e:18:14:62:4e:43:7b:20:e2:66:
                    b3:95:8a:99:a9:e3:a6:18:3c:8f:bd:23:da:02:4e:
                    56:f9:ce:2d:6d:54:6a:c8:15:0a:44:1d:5b:b4:0c:
                    d4:b5:58:aa:16:94:19:08:dc:9f:61:1b:f9:63:6a:
                    87:07:c5:81:a0:c3:44:ee:7a:34:70:a7:b8:a1:3f:
                    83:ce:a5:71:43:05:6d:80:15:63:6d:2c:ea:b8:54:
                    14:86:2f:21:1a:42:26:55:99:d7:43:59:dc:45:b0:
                    25:4d:7b:bb:c6:47:39:0b:0c:0e:fe:5d:3a:6d:7e:
                    95:0d:c6:93:78:1c:82:34:f8:4c:0f:07:f3:d0:a0:
                    79:e8:42:c0:fb:d3:2f:9b:76:8b:b5:8d:de:cc:b3:
                    7d:af:a2:4b:9a:9a:7b:86:fb:a9:b4:c6:93:99:40:
                    e9:f5:a9:74:27:23:11:36:f0:fa:ef:a6:5a:1f:aa:
                    9b:70:29:43:c0:f7:23:71:c4:fa:52:13:dd:93:7b:
                    90:57:9b
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                C3:D7:2B:CE:03:16:B7:7C:A1:3A:58:04:70:57:CD:72:CC:1C:B2:AC
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:C3:D7:2B:CE:03:16:B7:7C:A1:3A:58:04:70:57:CD:72:CC:1C:B2:AC

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         bc:44:d5:8f:d5:4f:d8:d6:96:14:f5:ed:be:36:19:96:22:ae:
         40:d2:38:ef:6f:a9:54:00:02:c1:31:b3:7a:cd:1e:0b:06:df:
         85:56:10:fc:fd:39:19:f8:8c:7f:ce:06:11:de:51:3a:8b:31:
         73:e8:8d:b9:bd:a1:a5:84:33:84:c8:44:48:53:f9:fe:28:69:
         62:d0:07:fc:43:11:cf:dc:f6:90:c2:db:15:fc:b7:0a:2c:c4:
         9c:ad:b3:fd:db:6f:1a:56:ca:ef:70:db:92:2f:27:e9:b5:ce:
         66:43:16:a0:da:18:96:2e:ef:90:78:51:b4:33:87:65:b5:99:
         59:28:08:f4:3b:47:d3:3b:f0:f3:e0:41:6b:0b:ae:a0:67:f1:
         99:56:b1:98:f0:92:20:f1:08:d0:58:db:97:a5:de:c6:1c:26:
         44:1e:aa:c0:c8:69:c1:bf:c3:75:14:01:76:a1:f6:a7:84:8e:
         d7:e6:69:8f:fa:3b:d5:f0:2d:98:12:d9:92:5e:82:9c:11:4b:
         7c:36:ed:6a:0f:db:c6:21:40:9b:dc:61:8b:04:f5:68:ec:41:
         f6:93:04:20:cb:a5:5f:3f:ea:71:00:dc:7e:47:07:0f:c3:f1:
         4b:05:99:a9:95:57:5f:a3:75:4f:32:e1:b4:b8:66:91:3f:35:
         d3:08:dc:4d:40:51:2b:2e:2c:04:e5:e5:33:8b:e6:82:50:1c:
         aa:8d:89:62:e7:34:bd:c3:c5:fa:ee:be:55:7d:e6:e0:d0:35:
         2e:5c:44:1c:35:b8:97:41:8d:e9:eb:83:60:fa:cb:6d:ed:c3:
         8e:38:75:a6:f3:72:de:71:a8:85:47:09:31:92:22:cd:2a:ce:
         27:f4:cd:f4:f6:15:f4:4b:12:6f:ea:8f:d3:fc:14:8d:fd:2f:
         b9:a6:20:ea:2a:c1:75:b6:6a:db:2b:53:ee:88:99:ee:4a:cf:
         c6:75:42:45:7a:e8:1f:ba:e9:6f:27:62:5c:6f:64:52:23:9e:
         91:5a:4d:e8:82:00:ff:6b:cb:d8:5b:c9:e1:ec:4a:6c:d8:dc:
         6a:95:64:de:30:b0:30:88:3e:ec:5c:fd:5b:ab:5b:d6:f2:bc:
         3d:4d:58:07:11:6e:a6:d3:67:b3:a0:2c:e3:a9:1e:72:46:35:
         3d:dd:c3:c6:d8:59:fd:c5:a2:03:a7:f3:71:c3:3b:72:48:81:
         a1:e4:48:b9:42:22:60:91:ca:b2:a7:b9:c9:ac:a9:8e:01:16:
         99:ca:aa:89:90:54:a4:97:87:f4:11:88:0d:db:76:8a:d8:29:
         b9:8e:b2:c5:98:19:e3:d8:13:e6:f0:5c:50:6c:cd:85:ae:38:
         79:1f:e9:47:1a:7b:1d:52
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            02:bd:8a:3e:42:2a:a5:47:81:c9:13:41:3b:7f:e1:a3:43:1b:53:9e
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, ST = CA, O = "MyOrg, Inc.", CN = root
        Validity
            Not Before: Nov 16 17:01:56 2023 GMT
            Not After : Mar 30 17:01:56 2025 GMT
        Subject: C = US, ST = CA, O = "MyOrg, Inc.", CN = intermediate
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:e8:ab:17:c5:80:c8:8a:c9:1d:b8:24:9b:4c:6e:
                    b1:36:a6:ca:7c:d8:77:99:d8:cc:86:92:f2:55:86:
                    6b:88:45:47:63:bd:6c:fc:68:6b:f0:d7:9d:3a:58:
                    fd:51:46:9f:f8:42:dd:b2:c4:ed:d0:b5:24:fc:06:
                    32:11:14:ac:34:06:8e:b2:7a:11:b9:66:14:93:f2:
                    79:ba:f7:56:27:84:51:b8:61:95:80:48:cf:48:55:
                    2a:80:5b:85:1c:dd:74:2c:9c:87:0e:aa:4e:7b:2f:
                    4f:eb:93:a8:93:7d:56:14:a3:79:7f:31:a7:cf:f4:
                    6b:1a:c7:f2:01:ba:2e:62:68:db:83:7e:4d:83:9b:
                    42:7b:1d:c2:21:dd:09:c5:d4:51:8a:76:4b:6d:1a:
                    e2:a9:bf:41:d3:65:e0:54:a2:02:5e:0f:83:e2:63:
                    dc:20:0b:93:2c:82:2f:b0:e9:44:c5:54:b4:c9:a4:
                    c6:d4:25:eb:fd:22:25:88:a8:5f:73:ef:1e:3d:ce:
                    4d:36:83:4c:36:46:03:fe:f9:49:1e:e4:24:b5:a6:
                    7d:ee:1f:5d:94:44:2c:b7:ef:b3:72:b1:35:1e:0a:
                    5f:1a:8a:74:57:bb:5a:f7:7a:53:19:68:03:4e:fb:
                    b0:fb:4f:48:ba:94:8f:20:69:5f:17:33:f2:42:ec:
                    1e:ab
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints:
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Key Usage:
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                IP Address:127.0.0.1, IP Address:192.168.73.120, IP Address:192.168.73.121
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         af:9e:95:5d:b1:d1:28:fd:be:7a:3a:ec:9f:92:76:d7:43:91:
         21:9d:d5:a8:dc:ac:ea:dd:96:f4:63:75:ab:74:51:26:55:7c:
         d3:97:61:7c:6a:72:f7:5d:a4:46:79:13:92:c6:df:69:a4:f0:
         d3:52:b2:a3:50:0c:9c:16:06:2d:4a:15:87:43:98:73:1c:1f:
         cf:28:20:f8:d4:37:77:ea:96:55:32:85:22:f4:56:de:b7:f5:
         da:a9:4e:52:3e:4a:41:7e:37:d2:a1:01:b1:3c:29:74:83:9f:
         9d:64:48:b8:4e:60:1f:8c:7e:b2:8c:1e:df:34:d8:26:75:36:
         ce:2d:cc:07:3b:6f:81:78:be:e0:ed:57:62:3e:cb:04:b6:44:
         6e:f8:65:d9:33:28:46:02:68:21:56:a4:14:9b:ef:74:a2:69:
         3d:b9:dd:38:9a:28:c7:8a:4f:ab:2a:70:f2:99:22:88:5d:ac:
         90:c2:47:c8:ee:6e:e6:dd:69:98:92:59:93:e7:29:21:88:78:
         88:a4:c3:2e:ba:27:7d:93:96:a5:53:22:81:40:87:42:fb:71:
         f6:58:8d:1d:d2:48:8f:b4:b4:bd:17:42:76:a1:aa:44:a7:44:
         bb:17:d4:bd:13:9f:f2:c8:eb:8c:c6:ac:06:2c:5b:c2:8a:a8:
         6f:f1:5d:ee:56:dc:8a:1a:65:0c:a7:f3:20:10:48:cf:7e:bc:
         05:09:71:ee:94:3a:80:c4:d3:ce:24:8c:e9:61:df:3d:3d:0f:
         c7:f5:4f:21:fe:46:34:a8:c9:c4:2f:5b:fd:be:15:ce:74:e4:
         be:b5:2a:1b:27:06:4b:87:e2:5a:cf:f9:af:0c:87:c1:8f:49:
         38:bd:e8:78:77:c0:33:a3:f7:28:18:ef:df:f1:ee:d1:bb:7d:
         66:50:ce:da:2b:ae:23:9d:4d:76:ee:b6:47:c8:96:08:45:04:
         37:5d:05:f9:22:3d:d9:13:26:d8:18:57:d2:1d:17:b7:1b:22:
         ca:92:6f:23:7d:ab:d0:c8:32:e9:82:d4:56:11:5b:26:d4:03:
         ec:fd:6f:54:8f:36:31:20:ed:d3:c1:23:ce:78:c6:32:80:9f:
         c5:30:9a:92:d3:ee:07:59:54:cd:3b:02:6f:58:5d:e7:61:5e:
         60:55:e8:7b:33:d6:aa:32:72:ea:0d:79:94:a9:b7:80:5b:02:
         21:36:29:1a:60:11:8a:41:3d:89:86:c3:f6:89:c6:2e:07:67:
         55:1a:ed:f7:b6:bd:90:80:85:e5:3f:b2:95:71:23:df:17:53:
         67:5a:94:30:ea:85:7a:fa:28:61:7b:e0:c1:a6:25:d7:d2:4a:
         c6:dd:52:74:5e:64:8b:0c
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            22:f2:9a:dd:db:78:77:07:f7:66:68:4e:18:c0:fd:23:8e:95:e1:75
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, ST = CA, O = "MyOrg, Inc.", CN = intermediate
        Validity
            Not Before: Nov 16 17:01:56 2023 GMT
            Not After : Mar 30 17:01:56 2025 GMT
        Subject: C = US, ST = CA, O = "MyOrg, Inc.", CN = user1
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:b3:f2:c0:e2:62:e6:e0:bd:31:90:fc:64:63:0e:
                    b4:9e:96:23:71:f2:f9:56:33:4b:b2:b8:a3:06:de:
                    74:66:c2:a7:ba:5a:24:3b:3a:4c:df:a8:93:57:c2:
                    5c:32:d1:66:c5:bf:95:cc:10:39:9f:61:8b:27:2c:
                    e8:47:39:b5:68:33:b6:0e:02:24:25:94:35:ae:48:
                    fe:8f:79:2c:0a:11:a6:8f:27:29:48:1b:26:59:61:
                    ec:df:03:98:43:a2:3c:3e:99:2a:fb:8f:71:56:f5:
                    1e:75:46:ad:5f:65:5c:59:4d:af:26:3b:b4:ab:ca:
                    4a:b8:ff:34:70:f3:f8:26:83:63:2b:7a:99:e5:0b:
                    30:c0:61:c0:81:43:f1:94:eb:26:44:40:be:99:fd:
                    ae:3b:4b:22:d5:7c:5e:2a:34:ff:3b:8b:c0:88:12:
                    ba:24:3a:d3:f8:31:03:43:1b:2a:e5:94:67:63:c1:
                    c3:a0:7c:a9:fc:d1:d6:ec:0c:ca:db:2d:ff:0a:6a:
                    da:77:6a:00:58:3e:c2:e1:6f:dd:dd:2c:ee:b0:f2:
                    07:89:65:f9:cf:9e:19:8e:a1:fd:7d:6a:bd:c1:d7:
                    5f:bd:ff:20:89:bf:cb:7d:7b:a1:b2:23:89:0e:45:
                    97:19:3c:1f:d6:5f:c4:a3:6d:ce:01:6c:68:92:b2:
                    e6:25
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints:
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Key Usage:
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                IP Address:127.0.0.1, IP Address:192.168.73.120, IP Address:192.168.73.121
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         c9:76:82:51:21:75:42:64:2c:ab:bb:62:66:a9:cf:78:1b:ff:
         37:2a:8f:63:b5:37:2c:22:75:fa:61:c7:70:9a:f8:17:75:ad:
         06:39:9d:7f:18:d6:3f:8c:bd:3b:9d:f4:5f:44:96:35:91:b8:
         5e:2f:c8:d7:6c:c7:08:01:2c:a1:ff:6a:5d:93:a3:2f:86:f3:
         d1:e6:5d:6e:55:6f:69:72:de:9c:ad:bc:b0:a3:c3:9f:dc:29:
         ee:81:a0:37:3f:ae:eb:72:86:5f:7c:60:0a:d1:08:e3:2c:7a:
         97:ea:e2:6e:40:4d:b9:9f:0e:62:7d:3c:14:94:d6:76:78:c5:
         68:63:a0:bf:65:69:b7:61:64:22:03:55:28:74:ac:a3:e7:58:
         83:95:3c:77:0f:9b:4d:c6:98:e7:0f:6d:14:f7:7d:d7:36:11:
         3d:1f:16:75:3d:19:19:72:83:22:fb:70:0d:16:b3:60:bd:f5:
         6a:90:c2:c1:e5:a5:d6:39:24:a6:14:b5:e4:77:5f:e6:74:74:
         c4:80:60:47:93:e3:45:54:9e:23:d7:bd:7b:ba:0a:44:3f:b5:
         cf:ef:32:fd:75:02:18:5f:44:79:be:4c:0a:c8:0d:c2:af:b0:
         44:f9:cb:ca:d8:ee:7a:f0:e9:22:e9:bd:9c:6b:f0:7d:94:c2:
         ba:de:73:7a
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

intermediate.crt: OK

C = US, ST = CA, O = "MyOrg, Inc.", CN = user1
error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate
error user1.crt: verification failed

intermediate.crt: OK
C = US, ST = CA, O = "MyOrg, Inc.", CN = user1
error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate
error user1.crt: verification failed

C = US, ST = CA, O = "MyOrg, Inc.", CN = intermediate
error 2 at 1 depth lookup: unable to get issuer certificate
error user1.crt: verification failed
```

Comment: In short: openssl expects a root certificate as trust anchor. If you only have an intermediate you need to specify `-partial_chain` to accept it as the trusted root of an incomplete (no root CA) chain.

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich this makes sense. But did I do something wrong in generation, since `openssl verify -verbose -CAfile rootca.crt intermediate.crt user1.crt` failed too, and `rootca.crt` is the root.

Comment: The verify command takes a list of certificates and verifies each **independently**. So what you did is basically the same as first checking the intermediate against the root (which succeeds) and then checking user1 against the root, but w/o considering the intermediate (which fails).

Comment: OK understood. Does it mean that if `openssl verify -CAfile rootca.crt intermediate.crt` and `openssl verify -CAfile intermediate.crt user1.crt` both return OK, the chain is valid? I tried `openssl verify -verbose -partial_chain -CAfile intermediate.crt user1.crt` and it fals to verify, with error *invalid CA certificate*. Looking man page now.

Comment: Take a look at the actual error message you get when validating user1 against the intermediate. I get `error 32 at 1 depth lookup: key usage does not include certificate signing`. This is because your intermediate is missing the right key usage, specifically keyCertSign. Added another question as duplicate which describes which key usage is needed

Comment: This solved the issue: https://superuser.com/questions/738612/openssl-ca-keyusage-extension. Adding parameter `keyUsage = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment, keyCertSign` in the extensions file, solved the problem